# My sick cat started to drink a lot of water after sickness

Tags: cats, health, drinking

So my cat is sick (fever, lost appetite, sleeping all day), doesn't want to eat or drink from yesterday, so I have to force feed my cat with wet canned food. And now he began to drink water by himself. Still not eating, but does it mean my cat started to get better?

Comment: Drinking water by himself again is good. But regularly drinking a lot more water than usual is bad. He might have eaten something bad and is now recovering.  The symptoms however sound more serious. Are the main symptoms (e.g. fever) going away as well as the reluctance to eat and drink?  Note that one possibility is poison, either from catching a poisoned rat or from eating slug pellets. These require veterinary treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the vet.! And my cat have these symptoms and turned out to have severe kidney failure.  Hurry up, because they get worse very quickly!

Comment: Welcome to Pets, I think your answer gives reasonable advice for this question, but optimally answers should be a bit longer than this; please consider adding some more information, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't have to be renal failure, but it's very sound advise to see a vet quickly in cases like this. A cat not eating for a few days is in itself dangerous and can be a cause for liver failure for example, which can be rapidly fatal.